# web3.py does not print Events `ValueError: No matching functions found`

Tags: solidity, web3.py

***Goal:*** I want to print logs of the smart contract, like I do on `web3.js`, using `web3.py`.

On `web3.js` side, following code piece works:

```
var event = myContract.LogJob({}, {fromBlock:0, toBlock:'latest'});
event.watch(function(error, result) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

---

But on the `web3.py` side following line returns: `[]`.

**=>** On my smart contract I did not use the `emit` keyword before (`event Deposit(...)`), could it be the reason?

Example Small Contract Piece:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20; 

contract Contract {

  function deposit(bytes32 _id) payable {
     LogJob(msg.sender);
  }
  event LogJob(address indexed _from);
}
```

--

`web3.py` call:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -W ignore::DeprecationWarning

from __future__ import print_function
import os, sys
from web3 import Web3
import json
from web3.providers.rpc import HTTPProvider

os.chdir(sys.path[0]);

web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))

fileAddr = open("address.json", "r")
contractAddress = fileAddr.read().replace("\n", "")

with open('abi.json', 'r') as abi_definition:
    abi = json.load(abi_definition)

Contract = web3.eth.contract(contractAddress, abi=abi);

transfer_filter = Contract.on('LogJob', {'filter': {'clusterAddr': clusterAddress}})
print(transfer_filter.get())
```

Returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getClusterInfo.py", line 54, in <module>
    transfer_filter = Contract.on('LogJob', {'filter': {'clusterAddr': clusterAddress}})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web3/utils/decorators.py", line 13, in _wrapper
    return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web3/contract.py", line 345, in on
    argument_filter_names,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web3/contract.py", line 647, in _find_matching_event_abi
    raise ValueError("No matching functions found")
ValueError: No matching functions found
```

=> On `web3.py` can we also filer events from specific `blockNumber`?

Comment: Could you update your question with some more info: Which version of web3.py are you on? (looks like v3) Would you add the code where you initialize the `myContract` instance?

Comment: You could try using  `ConciseContract`  -> `Contract = web3.eth.contract(contractAddress, abi=abi,ContractFactoryClass=ConciseContract) ` as per [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/31584/820).

Comment: It gives following output: `NameError: name 'ConciseContract' is not defined
`

Comment: On re-reading - the answer suggests _removing_ ` ConciseContract ` anyway...

Comment: Other idea - check `contractAddress` properly formatted - can you interact with contract at all?

Comment: Yes! with same `contractAddress` and `contractAbi` I can call all the other contract functions except events. @atomh33ls

Comment: I'm out of ideas right now... perhaps @carver will see the update...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been working for me (web3.py 4.0.0b11):

```
my_filter = contract.eventFilter('LogJob',{'fromBlock':0,'toBlock':'latest'})

print(my_filter.get_all_entries())
```

or

`print(my_filter.get_new_entries())`

After deploying contract like this:

```
contract = w3.eth.contract(abi=data,bytecode=bc)
tx_hash = contract.deploy(transaction={'from': w3.eth.accounts[0], 'gas': 10000000})
tx_receipt = w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
contract_address = tx_receipt['contractAddress']
contract_instance = w3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=abi, ContractFactoryClass=ConciseContract)
```

Note, I do have the `emit` keyword in the contract so haven't checked that...

It could matter if you've used `ConciseContract`  -> https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/31584/820

See the docs: http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#web3.contract.Contract.eventFilter

Also [Web3.py EventFilter.get_new_entries() always empty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36009/web3-py-eventfilter-get-new-entries-always-empty)

Comment: Its interesting that Events successfully show up on the `web3.js` side. I will try with emit keyword and see does it change anything. @atomh33ls

Comment: @Alper perhaps you could show how you created the `myContract` object?

Comment: myContract was just example that has the event section on my code. I used remix.solidity in order to deploy my contract. @atomh33ls

Comment: @Alper what do you get with `print(myContract)'?` I get `<class 'web3.utils.datatypes.Contract'>`

Comment: I get: `<web3.contract.Contract object at 0x7f8b5e299790>` @atomh33ls

Comment: When I tried your code I get: `AttributeError: 'Contract' object has no attribute 'eventFilter'` @atomh33ls

Comment: @Alper hmm.. what version are you using `web3.__version__`?

Comment: @Alper if you edit question to include web.py import and contract initialisation, it might be easier to help....

Comment: its: `web3==3.15.0`@atomh33ls

Comment: Just updated my question @atomh33ls

Comment: @Alper Looks like there might have been an [update to the filter mechanism](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/blob/master/docs/releases.rst#v400-beta1) in v4, so that might be why my answer didn't work for you...

Comment: Ah I tried to do this: `pip install --pre --upgrade web3` getting some error that I couldn't fix: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/7809c11938d2def4d6e97bed89da7f45 @atomh33ls

Comment: @Alper sounds like another question...

Comment: You are right, I already asked here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/43091/4575 but I guess error is related to pip side that I need to fix.

Comment: print(my_filter.get_all_entries()) prints bunch of information. How could I trim specific data variable? @atomh33ls